# how to choose a random string from available string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, sprite-kit

I have a few strings.

```
NSString *st1 = @"png1";
NSString *st2 = @"png2";
NSString *st3 = @"png3";
```

And I have a `SKTexture`.

```
SKTexture *Texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed: @"????"];
```

How can I choose a random string from `st1`, `st2` and `st3` at "????".

I tried it with `arc4random`, it worked only with integer, but with string I couldn't solve my problem.

Can anyone help me please? Thanks for answers.

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"st%d",integerValueFromArc4Random];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *a = @[st1, st2, st3];
SKTexture *Texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed: a[arc4random_uniform(a.count)]];
```

Comment: Hi Avt, i got the following error: Property 'length' not found on object of type 'NSArray *'